# I have trouble executing my PHP code when i open my HTML file

Tags: php, html

I have trouble executing this php code, which is supposed picks a random picutre in a folder i have.
I'm running my html code on a local hosted server with XAMPP, which, as far i can read, should support PHP.
I tried running the code through tiiny.host as well, but i dosen't seem like the code is executing there either.
The directory works but putting in manual numbers such as /pics/nftlist/10.png

```
 <div class="APE">
    <img src="/pics/nftlist/<?php $random = rand(7,207); echo($random); ?>.png" height="90">
 </div>
```

Any idea on what to do?
Thanks in advance!

[Web result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsNnG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called test.php and paste the following:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If it does not work your PHP is not configured.

Comment: change to .php made it work thanks:D

Comment: Great please close your question as solved then.